# How to print the bottom label of google gauge outside the guage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-gauges

I am trying to print the bottom label of the Google gauges outside(just below the respective gauges). Also, I want to provide two different suffixes for the two gauges. I have tried giving separate formatters(formatter1, formatter2) for both and separate data(data1 and data2), but it's not even drawing the gauges(no error). In this case, the `draw_data_guage` will have a fourth argument.

```js
var e = document.getElementById('draw_chart');
e.onclick = draw_data_gauge(80, 68, '%');

function draw_data_gauge(cpu_data, memory_data, suffix) {
  console.log("in guage")
  google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['gauge']
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      ['CPU', cpu_data],
      ['Memory', memory_data],
    ]);
    var options = {
      width: 500,
      height: 150,
      redFrom: 90,
      redTo: 100,
      yellowFrom: 75,
      yellowTo: 90,
      minorTicks: 5,
    };
    var formatter1 = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
      suffix: suffix,
    });
    formatter1.format(data1, 1);
    var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data1, options);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<input name="Button" type="button" value="Draw" id="draw_chart" />

<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

I want the gauge's bottom label to be displayed outside and be able to give separate suffixes for both the gauges. Consider this jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/8dLverqh/). I want to display the percentages(bottom label) outside the gauges just below them. My jsfiddle link is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rajii/dy94pqa6/36/). Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a fiddle working link of your problem, so that others can check and let you know possible solution

Comment: I have included a jsfiddle link for reference @Anant singh

Comment: Do you mean, the percentage text? Also, what do you mean by `different suffixes`? What for example? `%` vs `kbps`?

Comment: Yes. The percentage text. For eg., `80%`. It's displaying it on gauge now. I want to display it outside gauge just below it. Also, if you see the code, the same suffix is being used for both the gauges. But, I want to give different suffixes to different gauges. For eg: `80%` on one gauge and say `50&` for the other gauge. `%` and `&` are the suffixes.

Comment: I have included another jsfiddle link which is my exact code. The earlier one was just a similar one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your direction to separate the graphs is right. Here is how to do this:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {
    packages: ['gauge']
  });
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var options = {
      width: 400,
      height: 120,
      redFrom: 90,
      redTo: 100,
      yellowFrom: 75,
      yellowTo: 90,
      minorTicks: 5
    };

    var source = [{
        data: ['Memory', 80],
        suffix: '%'
      },
      {
        data: ['CPU', 55],
        suffix: '?'
      },
      {
        data: ['Network', 68],
        suffix: '$'
      },
    ];

    source.map((item, index) => {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Label', 'Value'],
        item.data
      ]);

      var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        suffix: item.suffix,
        fractionDigits: 0
      });
      formatter.format(data, 1);

      document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="chart_div_' + index + '"></div>';
      var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div_' + index));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    });


    // dynamic update, randomly assign new values and redraw
    //setInterval(function() {
    //  data.setValue(0, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
    //  formatter.format(data, 1);
    //  chart.draw(data, options);
    //}, 1000);
    //
    //setInterval(function() {
    //  data.setValue(1, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
    //  chart.draw(data, options);
    //}, 1000);
    //
    //setInterval(function() {
    //  data.setValue(2, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
    //  chart.draw(data, options);
    //}, 1000);
  }
</script>
```

About the text position, I think that it's impossible. You can add a `div` below each chart with the text.